# Trying to import elements from a text file to a list

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file that contains information about customers for a bus company booking system.
The file is laid out as such:

```
id, name, customer discount, total money spent
```

E.g. part of the file is:

```
C1, James, 0, 100
C2, Lily, 0, 30
```

I want to import this information to a list in Python, but I only need the ids and names.
I've tried a few different ways of importing the information, but I can only import the whole file to a list and even then it always comes out like this:

```
[['C1,' 'James,' '0', '100'], ['C2', 'Lily', '0', '30']]
```

And I don't even know how to begin separating the items so that I can just have the id and name in the list.

Comment: Take a look at the *csv* and/or *pandas* modules

Comment: What did you try so far? Share the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Since your text file contains comma-separated values, the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module likely will be most useful.

```
import csv

with open ('data.txt', 'r') as fh:
    header = [h.strip() for h in next(fh).split(',')] # remove spaces and assign the header to dictionary keys
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=header) # read the row contents assigning names to the fields
    for row in reader:
        print(row['id'], row['name'])
```

---

```
C1  James
C2  Lily
```

The useful part of the csv module reading the file as a dictionary assigns the column names to each row's field, making it easy to index which column names you want to select, such as `row['id']` and `row['name']`.

Also, since you mentioned you want to "just have the id and name in the list", at first create an empty list, then append each rows items to that list as so:

```
import csv

id_name = [] # list to store ids, names

with open ('data.txt', 'r') as fh:
    header = [h.strip() for h in next(fh).split(',')]
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=header)
    for row in reader:
        # print(row['id'], row['name'])
        id_name.append([row['id'], row['name']])

print(id_name) # print the resulting list
```

---

```
[['C1', ' James'], ['C2', ' Lily']]
```